# Are digital accelerometer readings instantaneous snapshots?

Tags: accelerometer

Trying to understand the internal mechanics of digital accelerometers a bit better.  I realize that the answer may vary depending on accelerometer type or manufacturer, but would like to get a general idea of what to expect.

Let's say I have a sample rate of 1kHz, and am getting a reading (interrupt) exactly every 1ms starting at 0.

If a half-sine impulse is applied directly between 2 samples, will any of that impulse be included in the next measurement output?

An attempt to draw below:

[image: Example]

The instantaneous reading at both 1.000ms and 2.000ms is near 0.

However, in between those samples was a half-sine of 25g.

Will the data acquired at the 2ms sample be 0?  25?  Some integrated value in between?

Appreciate any input, thanks!

Comment: What is the bandwidth of the accelerometer?  In general, if the bandwidth is high relative to the sampling interval then you can think of the measurement as instantaneous.

Comment: Bandwidth on this chip is half of the Data Rate. So for my example, bandwidth of 500Hz.  Are you able to elaborate on that?

Comment: You must specify the dynamic range and % error tolerances with sampling rate to answer this.

Comment: Are you familiar with Nyquist sampling? Putting a 500 Hz low pass filter means that you will never miss anything (can reconstruct anything up to 500 Hz), and you can simulate the output by filtering the input with your filter response.

Comment: Might be mistaken, but I think you're still talking about assuming everything is instantaneous readouts though, which is the original uncertainty?  My example above is an impulse much faster than 500 Hz, say around 2000Hz.  The question is more about common internal workings of real MEMs accelerometers. 
 Would it be common for the chip to internally average or integrate the readouts?

Comment: You said that the bandwidth of your sensor is 500 Hz.  That means that your impulse is low pass filtered and only the component of the impulse below 500 Hz is sampled.  Presumably your datasheet can give you more information about how it does that filtering to remove frequencies above 500 Hz.

Comment: Got it, thanks - I guess that means I'm really looking for more info on the filter which I don't see much of in the datasheet other than a cutoff frequency.  Chip is H3LIS331DL just for completeness.

Comment: The bandwidth of that sensor is 780 Hz when sampled at 1 KHz, so it is not Nyquist sampled and so you can miss short events, or at least measure them inaccurately.  If you want to measure fast impulses, this is probably not the best sensor to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample at those times is equal to zero

Here I made a design in a picture that is worth 1.7 MBytes. The scope plot shows the input, output and the difference error.

[image]

Please ask a question to resolve your uncertainty.

Notice  I used a 1/2 wave of 500 Hz. Then I use a sweep FM and converted it to a sampling pulse to see sampling rates from  1kHz to 10 kHz or 2x to 20x the half sinewave which has a step edge of a very high bandwidth.  I can see that the % amplitude error is proportional to the ratio of the oversampling rate.

Now that you provided the MEMs P/N for accelerometer, you will notice the absense of analog error specs because with Shannon's Theory, the high frequency AC signals below 500 Hz sampling rate will have significant aliasing error and the the amount of spectrum below 250 Hz affects the accuracy too. You can only detect 250 Hz if it is synchronous to the peaks otherwise the amplitudes error with also modulate with the difference frequency.

To illustrate this I simulated an ADC S&H with variable f input , an error amplify, LPF and true peak detector.
[image]

When you slide Sig gen frequency. [you can stop and analyze the signals (3 Outs)](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgTCAMB0l3BWEDoE4DMAWMqGXQGwDs6qYkAHMpMtcgKYC0AjMwFABKIqzERFmbgRr9BNZtRpIYRKFGgI2AcxCZmBEEQQQ1G0XMhsA8smEgCFKsKuWDbAE6r1525lQaLVGunSHmCVFV3FyptGy95OAhmeFj4B01IQQpnLQgUjXF4gHdNbU0BPPTnQ1yiJILBNMqoNgBjROTMKnLkkpBmaDAmKhZoIl4CDAE1BAptVCImHEjIdn9BYnS4ZF4QChWaCCllRvXmvYoCMVrchDXW1eWaUuQwcNMaT1qVBDMSDTeRCzsGr81CI8QnJmD1VNAjjg3JR0BsAlpZuwyhV9EsardLhlzERipl6utjjUeHxCjdYPAJJ1iLwBvgKOgBswiNhEWwAJIEqqFDYiUnyJCKXI8mrVfSGRxHLnJQn07YdeJcSXrdDpGUHG6qLYKAz8tgAQ3MmCeRvWK2ONCo-hALCQMTi1rA0Ew6GYmGOzQQ2Fd9wdTpdmGZnuYqEgOAosjtOSBzwQRA8b1qjnN5jAgjdi1TILicASyYC12QZCz2bYQrNJuF%20dOhqembzRduumB6ZTYlzJoICdj8cy8pLSY7tmFzyyJZUw6HKxxGtuyc7HkHXlL3AuhWJmnItSN6CCGgEVkz6-EzAA%20pgT5AT4QjgQTwgL9BTywT%20wTLwE8JxL5Fptagb15%203D5IBrAdEgNp9rEHT9P4BCdiGQzdpSMFvPSkAEIQ6jELgkE5rkAGUCuEDztWAEJrgxEJrc65VhQwRVoYDR0T26zBAMcowHEkbZtm0QoRYvgYQQWFEDhnFzMuzGFukwQkeKrGfEW%207SXI5AoLgKSusw6BvPBCTKbRKwMeAkDqWMrBqDpcEBLsUnsQpG4RIx%20yhJgggUcgbkGOScCumQFDkCqvhgFo2gaIwMjjAgLoBeUQxGj64lIi5nlNKEDbLh5gEeQxmX5FWOVedRwHkcBmz6vKhIgTEP7HmB1pWtxKzoNAxApKZGyMrKSAtW13pjCkcakBoTXLjEVWEeNixUWN6HTSNNXmDNuRTSpNXpds%20LrUtI1JC0axklxPHHRAvX8P1lhMhhwRJbNBxVttckJNtD3wCpUgEI6nj4OQbjlDwz1vQV%20UNqYX2WD9SSTJAAMqNt9nw4ltQNJGqUdItnonOJ8DkMd2ZeLAGQhcJJD%20LGzo7rdK1A15qO5Sti3VRU9Po8zRasMzRVjYzCYc7Vf4dGAzggWAH4rKBVoQU1ZKxvwSSmdpqBuikBOyxsqABUrOnBmMuG3LwwuTULLH68bO2Cx%20y2C84D24%209W12yRvBTgdswUnjvH8kQcsa1C2saayK127bZozY4ztSOz-gQMZcYUK1bqusJ4wMtFz3R2tGOg3HCfCYnKdaOguwR5oawlziTlbRnmMW58RVu75kADKJxBDDibkhhGMHEHGOI8JjJDSOSyWsPltPVxlQdi%20IouKZtU9z7XaOm5bI2z%20Y5UAB4EjQbiWmp1ASIIma4wAOgAzgAEgAXhfBAAC4XwA9vYAAm9D2BfABCACu9-3x-bIL974AAsL4ABkAAKAAxTgIBCBPFsN%20YE4gwJUloDOBQW03KhDMK6A4wlezY18uAJ05xmSEECqJZ0cZWThwQXcS0TYwhyB8LEYuTZCEdE4SqOwK1mE%20i0nXNsK0GFcMVsREocDtJmBYTI3eN05AmmkN5RQ9DZF4LEe0Ua98l413kcvDo1pMBOjAELXASsjimRig1aADJZ7nDwNpZ04Zdo0HfgAMz1D-AANvfMapAY6aI0TcNguiJFAiEUCGgLBoK4HwEMcg0cEI4QigoOYDI3LMEsHga80QVieO8X4sazDaFRK4c5CJ-wIkVIbnMOJuTElzAmOhMSw8AlFnEZwqR-CbaCJwYw6s5TnD4KsD07h908EDJYYYbe74kDQm4cQIIO5j6CEgfQPUABrC%20p89QX0vk-Hxr8L52gALbnzYNvY4Eh-iiVuRhVQ4BBAAFF7D2BfhfAAIvQABdR74vyuSmPQcF1hmM0EMJ5mZIG%20PPvQC%20Sh6AADsP56gBZ-c%20YAPFAswLrayyA8DmB%20IIV0IAADKeozkAAcfHwvPnsg5RzX4JE4UgswI5qDGAmbg8QAYgkzjYE-cATyvzoQ0CYywAhslwG9tYAMbsJDeHgSojYtRYSaECNAiQO4YjgEJbE6B9h6AAEcf7IrqAATzYEAA)
Any new Questions?

Comment: The datasheet specs out a few things.  Output data rate (1khz), bandwidth (500hz), and low pass filter cut-off (780Hz).  It doesn't provide much on the curve of the filter.  Am I to assume that is the 3dB point - such that if the 25g impulse in my example was 780 Hz, it would readout 12.5g?

Comment: Is that your only question? or do you want to understand. The phase can make the error 0 to 100%